# Creating a dylib file on MacOS for use with Python wrapper of Steamworks API

Tags: python, c++, xcode, dylib, steamworks-api

I am a hobbyist programmer trying to integrate the [SteamworksForPython API](https://gramps.github.io/SteamworksForPython/) into a Python-based game. This API is a Python wrapper of the [Steamworks API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/home), which only officially supports C++. I am working on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Blindly following the documentation, I have done the following:

1. I have downloaded the SteamworksForPython repo.
2. I have added the steam header directory from the Steamworks SDK (/sdk/public/steam) to that repo.
3. I have added to that repo the Steam API file appropriate to my operating system (in my case, libsteam_api.dylib from /sdk/redistributable_bin/osx32).

The next step listed in the documentation is to create a new dylib file. Unfortunately, the steps to do this haven't been described for MacOS yet.

Looking at the process for Linux and Windows, it seems like I need to create this dynamic library file using the repo's SteamworksPy.cpp file and the steam_api.h header file from the Steamworks SDK.

I have researched how to create a dylib file using Xcode and am currently trying to do it. The process seems similar to the one described by the [documentation](https://gramps.github.io/SteamworksForPython/) for Windows using Visual Studio.

I have done the following:

1. I have created a new Xcode project of type plain C++ dynamic library.
2. I have added SteamworksPy.cpp into the *Compile Sources* list.
3. I have added steam_api.h to the *Headers* list (under public, not private or project).
4. I have added libsteam_api.dylib to the *Link Binary With Libraries* section.

I am getting an error when I try to build, however. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

And here is a more explicit screenshot of the linker error:

[image]

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430432/ld-library-not-found), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682156/ld-library-not-found-for-lgsl), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358591/xcode-library-not-found), I think the problem is that Xcode doesn't know where to look for the library I'm trying to link to, so I need to tell it where to look. This should be simple, but I can't manage to do it.

**Can anyone give me advice on how to proceed?**

---

Similar questions that were helpful, but didn't lead me to a solution:

- [How do I create a dynamic library (dylib) with Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194485/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-library-dylib-with-xcode)
- [Building and Using a DYLIB in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955272/building-and-using-a-dylib-in-xcode)
- [ld: library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430432/ld-library-not-found)
- [ld: library not found for -lgsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682156/ld-library-not-found-for-lgsl)
- [xcode library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358591/xcode-library-not-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem.

Xcode couldn't find the location of the library I was trying to link to.

I noticed that under *Build Settings* I could specify *Path to Link Map File*. I tried to hardcode the path to where my library (libsteam_api.dylib) resided, but I got the same error described above.

Then I did something that worked.

I deleted the reference to the library in the *Link Binary With Libraries* section.

Then I moved the library from its original location into my Xcode project directory.

Then I used the file selection pane in the *Link Binary With Libraries* section to reselect the library from the Xcode directory.

When I built, everything worked fine.