# What is better to use in a Cocoa application: dynamic libraries or static libraries?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I need to use a library in a Cocoa application and can use either a dynamic (`.dynlib`) or a static (`.a`) version of it. I came from Linux world and would happily use the dynlib. However, since the app bundle will contain all the dependencies (including the dynlib) I thought it would not be a problem to have a bigger binary due to the static linking. What is the best solution?

Comment: iphone-sdk allows linking dynamic libraries ? (I'm not sure ...)

Comment: @mihirmehta: Cocoa is present on Macs as well.

Comment: And the cocoa tag is for questions about Cocoa on Mac OS X. For iOS, Apple uses the phrase Cocoa Touch and the corresponding Stack Overflow tag is cocoa-touch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, my concern would be responsiveness with respect to loading time of big executable vs. small executable and multiple libraries. The difference may be small.

Comment: Well, I am assuming the standard in Mac OS is to put all dynamic libraries inside the bundle (`.app`) anyway, which would mean that the library would always be download, either as an extra file or inside the binary. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: I don't mean the download time of the installation package from a remote server to the local hard disk drive. I mean the loading time of the executable from hard disk drive to RAM.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand now. I could link statically any library that will be inevitably called, and link dynamically any library that _could_ be called, and probably the difference will be imperceptible. I am planning to use static linking then.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `dynamic library` `.dylib` but you are able to create a `dynamic framework` with `.dylib` inside. The answer depends on your needs

[[iOS static vs dynamic library]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857639/4770877)

[[Create Objective-C dynamic framework]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216112/4770877)

Answer (score -1):

iOS app should NOT have any dynamic libraries. Your only option is to statically link code.

Comment: -1: This question is about Cocoa, and Cocoa applications can certainly use dynamic libraries.

Comment: I am not developing for iOS: my application is for Mac OS.